# Page speed affecting ranking in practice

Tags: search-engines, performance, ranking

[Articles like this one](http://www.webpronews.com/topnews/2009/11/13/google-page-speed-may-be-a-ranking-factor-in-2010) discuss Google possibly taking speed into account for ranking factors.

Are there any other search engines which already take speed into account for search results? or perhaps a labs version of Google that takes it into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked around a lot myself for this answer and if Bing or Yahoo does take it into account then they have not release to the public that they do.

Also, take a look at http://www.free-seo-news.com/newsletter416.htm.  Google has stated that adding in page speed will change less than 1% of search results.

Google uses over 200 criteria to return results for pages.  Page speed is probably one of the most minor.

In general you will lose more visitors because your page is to slow and people will leave, rather than Google reducing your ranking because of how slow your site is.

Answer (score 2):

[Google does now take page speed](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) as a factor in it's ranking. But as Matt Cutts said, it's only [1 of 200 factors](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/), so they don't recommend spending a lot of time on this just for search engines, but you should instead focus on making the site fast for the user because you will keep more visitors this way.

I don't know if other search engines include this in their ranking, although Yahoo has [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) so it wouldn't surprise me if they also included it as a factor.

Also, check out Google's web master tools which has a [graph and other information](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/your-sites-performance-in-webmaster.html) about a sites speed.