# effect of page speed on ad revenue

Tags: advertising, statistics, page-speed, revenue, studies

I'm thinking of slowing my pageloads a bit, and want to know how much ad revenue will decrease due to the slowness.

For ads on a revenue-per-impression (CPM) basis, I have to worry about

- decreased initial traffic ("landings", if you will) and
- an increase in the number of people who leave.

[The second one — those who leave — has been covered.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/568) But is there a good, recent study on the decrease in landings? (One thing that affects landings is [the fact that Google shows a slower-loading page lower among search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1518), though general site reputation also depends on page speed and affects landings.)

And as to ads on revenue-per-click (CPC) basis: Are there any data on the decrease in clicks when pages are slower-loading? (E.g., on whether those fewer people who stick around on a slower site are those who click more (or less), and to what extent.)

Comment: I have to ask - why on earth would you want to slow down your page loads a bit?

Comment: @James, it's a by-product of adding stuff to the pages.

Comment: You can usually add whatever you need to add in an asynchronous way without slowing down the page.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any data that directly correlates page speed with click thrus. However, [this article](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/12/web-performance-optimization-is-the-new-seo/) shows how important page speed is in a variety of other areas and may be useful to you:

> - Amazon: 100 ms delay caused a [drop in revenue](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2006/11/marissa-mayer-at-web-20.html).
> - Google: 400 ms delay caused a [0.59% decrease in search requests per
>     user](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/8523).
> - Yahoo!: 400 ms delay caused a [5-9% decrease in traffi](http://www.slideshare.net/stoyan/dont-make-me-wait-or-building-highperformance-web-applications)c.
> - Bing: 2 seconds delay caused a [4.3% drop in revenue per user](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/8523).
> - Mozilla made their download page 2.2 seconds faster and was rewarded
>     with an increase of [15.4% in downloads](http://blog.mozilla.com/metrics/category/website-optimization/).
> - Google Maps reduced the file volume by 30% and observed a [30%
>     increase in map requests](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10784_3-9954972-7.html).
> - Netflix, which uses Appdynamics to monitor their performance,
>     enabled gzip on the server; simply by this single action pages became
>     13-25% faster and [saved 50% of traffic volume](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2008/public/schedule/detail/3632)!
> - Shopzilla succeeded in reducing the loading time from 7 down to 2
>     seconds, whereby the [conversion rate increased by 7-12](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/7709), they observed
>     a 25% increase in page requests, they were able to [retire 50% of their
>     servers](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/06/how-green-is-your-web-page/), thus saving energy costs.
> - AOL observed the [number of page views on several websites](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16878352/The-Secret-Weapons-of-the-AOL-Optimization-Team). While the
>     fastest users requested 7-8 pages, the slowest only viewed 3-4.
> - Edmunds got down from over 10 seconds to less than 2, adding 17%
>     page views and [increasing revenue by 3%](http://technology.edmunds.com/blog/2010/11/how-edmunds-got-in-the-fast-lane.html).

Comment: +1; thanks. I've looked at some of these, none of which show a lot of info, and will look at the rest.